# CD digital audio ripping tool for OS X that has accurate extraction, error detection, and verbose reporting?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, audio, music, optical-drive

I'm almost ready to say I have found a good OS X replacement for every piece of software I use on Windows (excluding some Windows development tools), but there's still this gap to fill:

For CD digital audio ripping / extraction, I use a tool on Windows called [EAC - Exact Audio Copy](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/).  I like EAC because:

- it supports a very **reliable** extraction mode by default,
- it takes advantage of drive features like **C2 error correction**
  (and will tell you if your CD-ROM drive doesn't have it)
- it **validates tracks** were ripped accurately by consulting an online database, and
- it **reports verbose details** about potential issues, when they arise, and I can then listen to the track to see if the issues are perceptible or not.

In a nutshell, I can be confident whether a track was reliably ripped or not when using EAC.

I don't get this sense of confidence from iTunes.  iTunes has an option under *Import Settings* to *Use error correction when reading Audio CDs*, but that seems to be the extent of reliability-oriented settings in iTunes. Currently, I'll use iTunes if the disc I'm ripping appears pristine and without scratches – otherwise I turn to EAC.

Is there an application for OS X that, like EAC above, focuses on *reliable* CD digital audio extraction and provides detailed information?  Thank you.

Comment: I miss EAC too, great, great app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [XLD](http://tmkk.pv.land.to/xld/index_e.html)

It started out as decoder/encoder/transcoder tool but it's branched out in to ripping in recent years (version 20080812 and above have ripping features) and it supports most of your criteria:

- Uses the [AccurateRip](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=AccurateRip) technology, comparing MD5 sums against known-good library of rips to ensure the rip was done correctly.
- Uses [cdparanoia](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Cdparanoia) 10.2 as the ripping and error correction library. Can be used on drives that don't have Accurate Stream and utilize C2 error pointers.

([Source](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=XLD) for above)

I can't comment on the "verbose details when errors arise" request because I've never encountered an error ripping with it.

It's free. It will multi-thread to speed up encoding of albums. And it's pretty fast. It's been my encoder/transcoder of choice for years now.