# How do I confirm that an audio CD has been converted to bin/cue bit for bit

Tags: copy-paste, archive

I am archiving my CD collection onto an external hard drive. I have been using Toast to create bin/cue files so that I will have an exact copy of each CD. However, many of the bin/cue files are being copied with gaps or dropped sound in them. When I rip the same CDs into MP3 or Apple Lossless, the music transfers without any drops/gaps. Is there any way to ensure that the bin/cue file is copying the CD bit for bit? And how do I know whether the problem is Toast or the CD drive?

Comment: Hi Ken, welcome to the site.  Does the following question/answers help at all? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45869/cd-digital-audio-ripping-tool-for-os-x-that-has-accurate-extraction-error-detec

Comment: That information is certainly helpful, but doesn't quite address what I'm looking for. I am able to rip the music without a problem. But I'd like to store an actual digital copy of the CD as bin/cue files on the hard drive as well.