# How to replace an MP3 or M4A in iTunes with a higher quality file, without having to re-do playlists containing the track?

Tags: itunes, mp3, macos, quality, m4a

I have in my iTunes library some songs that, years ago, I ripped from CDs at bit rates of only 128kbps.  Storage is cheap now and I'd like to replace those songs with higher-quality versions (e.g. 320kbps for the MP3s.)

I do intend to **re-rip** some of my source material (the music I listen to most often) at the higher bit rate.  I *don't* use iTunes itself for my ripping; I use [another ripping tool](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45869/cd-digital-audio-ripping-tool-for-os-x-that-has-accurate-extraction-error-detec).

Is there a way in iTunes for me to replace the lower bit rate version of a track with the new higher bit rate version, **without** having to re-add the track to playlists already containing it?  Could I just slip in the new version of the MP3 (assuming same name) with a filesystem copy, or is that liable to cause problems in iTunes?  How can I avoid having to manually copy metadata or manage playlists affected?

p.s. I already know about iTunes Match.  Please assume (for the purpose of this question) that I'm not interested in the automatic upgrading it can provide. Looking for a solution that will work without Match, or when Match can't upgrade a track.  Thanks.

Comment: Not totally sure if this will work for what you're asking, but check out [this Doug's script](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=relocateselected).

Comment: what I do now is create iTunes Media/Music/dummy/dummy/dummy.mp3 artist/album and put all my new songs there, because itunes organizes songs after locating them and deletes the folder if dummy.mp3 isn't there. CMD+F, select song, Enter, CMD+Shift+R to show in finder, CMD+Opt+Delete, tab space, CMD+W, Cmd+Tab, Cmd+I, Enter, if the location doesn't start in dummy, select dummy, Esc, then do CMD+I again so it starts the search there, down arrow to select the song, Enter, Enter, repeat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just replace the file in the filesystem.

Unfortunately, iTunes is too clever for it's own boots and registers for Finder events. So renaming a file in Finder will update it's location in iTunes *if iTunes is open!*

So here's one way I've tried that works.

1. Quit iTunes (actually quit, not just close window);
2. Locate the file in Finder:

   - This could be done in iTunes (before quitting) by right-clicking and choosing `Show in Finder`;
3. Replace the file in Finder with one with the exact same filename;
4. Open iTunes

iTunes will then use this file when you attempt to play it. Note: if any of the ID3 tags differ they will be updated in iTunes too (which is probably what you want). This means if you replace it with a file with the same file name but with less information in the metadata, you'll have less information in the iTunes browser.

Comment: but I was just wondering with this method, if the old mp3 files had album art in it, would the new file have the old album art as well?

Comment: It will use the metadata in the new file I believe. You'll have to try it, but I think the new file will not have album art (unless it happened to from the source you got it from). Normally it's just a case of clicking _Get Album Art_ though.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a python tool named **[replica](https://github.com/KraYmer/replica)** that automates the task of replacing file while keeping id3 infos of the old file. `pip install replica` to install.
My use case is that I often download upgraded versions (bitratewise) of my favourites mp3 albums and am particularly interested to keep my ratings (that i duplicate in the `grouping` tag).

Usage :

> If you replicate full albums, please make sure that tracks filenames
>   are similarly ordered in both source and destination folders.::
>
> ```
> $ replica -u Library/Sam_Cooke-Ain_t_that_good_news-128kbps-2003
> Incoming/sam_cook-good-news-320kbps   
> Cloning id3 metadata... Done  
> Renaming files......... Done
> ```
>
> In addition to id3 cloning, replica can handle files renaming too so
>   that *upgrading* mp3 files becomes a no-brainer.
>   Consider the
>   `-u` option to remove the source files and replace them by their
>   upgraded version. Preserving filepaths enables you to migrate id3
>   metatags to new files while keeping the information stored by your
>   music player (such as ratings or play counts) valid.

Answer (score 4):

The currently (March 2019) chosen answer is from 2012, and the other answers date back at least to 2014. This thread ranks high in Google search results for this problem, so I thought it would be worth pointing out that, in some circumstances, current versions of iTunes make this much simpler. *If* your new tracks have the same album, artist, song, and genre, when you import them into iTunes, *then* iTunes will recognize that they are duplicates, and ask if you want to replace the old versions with the new ones. Doing so *keeps the current metadata*, including play counts, playlist membership, etc.. Even the "date added" metadata is retained, keeping the original add date ("date modified" will be the current date).

I just re-ripped tracks from a CD I ripped back in 2005. The 2005 rip was done using iTunes's MP3 encoder; the new ones were done with iTunes's AAC encoder. Even with the different format, iTunes recognized the tracks and offered to replace them. After the replacement, I verified things like add date, play count, and playlist membership for the files. It worked perfectly.

I learned of this from the MacWorld hints forum: [Replace Songs in iTunes with Higher Quality Versions Keeping Stats - Mac OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080812213131421).

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading iTunes files to higher quality without losing metadata

Turn off iTunes Match.

Rip higher quality version to iTunes.

Go to higher quality file. Right click - Show in Finder

Go to file to be replaced. Right click - Show in Finder

Quit iTunes

In Finder delete lower quality file - move to trash - empty trash

Drag higher quality file to where lower quality one was

Open iTunes - play track from location of old file

Song could not be found - locate

Repeat

Now you have duplicate images in iTunes.  To delete these you need to follow 
these next steps.

Highlight all the redundant tracks in iTunes. Delete. Delete Songs. Keep 
Files.

Turn on iTunes Match.

Bingo.

Comment: this is the best answer, you have to empty trash

Answer (score 1):

For re-ripping your CD collection to a higher bitrate without losing all your ID tags, dates, plays, etc. use this [Copy Track Info to CD script](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=trackinfotocdtracks).

Answer (score -1):

Or you can briefly change the date on your computer to the date that the song was added, that way it won't interfere with your recently added playlists, etc.

However, this requires extra steps:

You must re-sort your recently added to be descending by Date Added rather than sorted by the left hand side numbers. Then sync your iPod.